# Swift Append every second item to Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append, enumeration

I have a swift array "Monthdata" that I want to append every second value in my months array.

```
var monthData = []
let months = ["Jul 12","Aug 12","Sep 12","Oct 12"]

for month in months {
 self.monthData.append(month)
}
```

So basically I the monthData array to look like:

```
["Aug 12","Oct 12"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use modulo operator ( % )

```
var monthData = Array<String>()
let months = ["Jul 12","Aug 12","Sep 12","Oct 12"]

var i : Int = 1

for month in months{
    if(i%2 == 0){
        monthData.append(month)
    }
    i = i + 1
}

println(monthData)
```

**Output :**

> [Aug 12, Oct 12]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the swift array `filter` method to get the filtered array,

```
monthData = months.filter{ (dataValue) in (find(months, dataValue)! % 2 != 0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3** (based on @maxkonovalov's answer)

```
let array = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let step = 2
let filtered = array.enumerated().flatMap { $0.offset % step == 0 ? $0.element : nil }

// filtered: ["0", "2", "4", "6", "8"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a more compact version to filter an array by element's index.

An example of how to find every Nth element in an array (swift 2.0):

```
let array = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let n = 2
let filteredArray =  array.enumerate().flatMap { $0.index % n == 0 ? $0.element : nil }

// filteredArray = ["0", "2", "4", "6", "8"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you can use a [Strides](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideto) class and a `map` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideto/1689074-map):

```
let months = ["Jul 12","Aug 12","Sep 12","Oct 12"]
let monthData = stride(from: 1, to: months.count, by: 2).map { (value:Int) -> String in
    return months[value]
}
print(monthData)
```